# Cannot access reverse relationship in Django OneToOneField Models

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am trying to extend the user model by following the instructions [here](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone) and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/).

I am having a model named Profile like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.TextField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    organization = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

EDIT:

Here is how I handle changes to User

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

I would expect to be able to access the model like:

```
>>>> user = User.objects.get(pk=23)
>>>> user.profile
```

Instead I am getting the error described here(a bit long to paste): https://pastebin.com/NRQVM0NK

Do you have any hints to unstuck me?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is typically the case if a `User` has no `Profile`. A `OneToOneField` (although the name might hint that), is in fact in essence a `ForeignKey` with a `unique=True` constraint on it.

Comment: Did you actually added the model to an `app` that you are *loading* (the app is in `INSTALLED_APPS`)?

Comment: I have just done an edit to show how I am handling changes to User model in respect to Profile. Also I have added the app to the installed apps.

Comment: I think there is something bad with the update, indeed :-/

Comment: Did you put signals in the models.py file? If you wrote them in signals.py file import did you import signals inside AppConfig class's ready method(it's in apps.py file)? And what django version do you use? It can be because your signal didn't fired.

Comment: I am using Django 2.1 and the signals are inside models.py

Comment: Did you try to put your signals inside signals.py and import it inside AppNameConfig class's ready method definition. It is something like this and is in apps.py.
```class YourAppNameConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'rest'


    def ready(self):
        import rest.signals```

Comment: And you should also check if it is in INSTALLED_APPS list in settings.py.

Comment: No I didnt and I am not familiar with the concept of AppNameConfig to be honest. Could you point me to the documentation please?